# Отправка почтового сообщения

Tags: php

Почему выдаёт ошибку?

Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for /php/book/mail/index.php in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\php\book\mail\index.php on line 14

Письмо успешно отправлено

```
<?php 
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=KOI-R\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: server <someone@somewhere.ru>\r\n\r\n";
?>

<?php
    $theme = 'Отчёт с сайта';
    $theme = convert_cyr_string($theme, 'w', 'k');

    $message = "<html>
                <head></head>
                <body>
                Письмо отправлено - ".date("d.m.Y H:i:s")."<br>
                Размер скрипта отправителя - ".filesize($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."
                </body>
                </html>";

    $message = convert_cyr_string($message, 'w', 'k');
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=KOI-R\r\n";
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $eaders)){
        echo "Письмо успешно отправлено";
    }

    else{
        echo "Произошла ошибка - письмо не отправлено";
    }
?>
```

Делаю по книге Самоучитель PHP5/6

Comment: попробуйте вместо `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` использовать `__FILE__`

Comment: Спасибо помогло, а куда оно отправилось?

Comment: Тут вот документация по функции [mail](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php) там все написано.